# MySQL: Why do these queries return different results?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_d1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM `user_d1` 
              WHERE birthdate BETWEEN '1989-08-04' AND '1991-08-04') 
ORDER BY timestamp_lastonline DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_d1 
WHERE birthdate BETWEEN '1989-08-04' AND '1991-08-04' 
ORDER BY timestamp_lastonline DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

And what I really don't understand: why does **Query 2** return the wrong results? It returns a list ordered first by `birthdate` and then by `timestamp_lastonline`...

Comment: Oh, that is a pity that Tim deleted his answer, it was very helpful (connecting the PK from the inner and the outer query): `SELECT * FROM user_d1 uo WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_d1 ui WHERE ui.birthdate BETWEEN '1989-08-04' AND '1991-08-04' AND ui.id=uo.id) ORDER BY uo.timestamp_lastonline DESC LIMIT 20`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Query 1** : If at least one record between the dates **exists** then the entire talbe is retrieved.

**Query 2** : Only records between the dates are retrieved.

Read [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) for how `EXISTS` works.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query uses BETWEEN to return every entry BETWEEN the first entry with `'1989-08-04'` and the next entry with `'1991-08-04'` and then orders these by `timestamp_lastonline DESC`. Note that this is literally returning the entries between the two entries with those two values, not every entry that has a year between 1989 and 1991(unless you manually ordered these to be chronologically indexed!). I'm interested to see what you think your first query returns, as it'll get every entry in the table ordered by `timestamp_lastonline` if there's a row that the BETWEEN clause returns.